# .NET Logging Class with Fluent Configuration

Tags: .net, logging, log4net

Is there a .NET logging class that does not rely on XML configuration files? I thought is was possible with log4net but can't find any info.

Comment: Hey @Detroitpro, are you sure it should be Community Wiki? Doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

[Serilog](http://serilog.net) is configured in code. E.g.:

```
var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
  .WriteTo.RollingFile("logs\\myapp-{Date}.txt")
  .CreateLogger();

log.Information("Hello, world!");
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe [ClearInsights Logging](https://clearinsights.io/) will work for you.

Code implementation example:

```
using IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
.ConfigureLogging(builder =>
    builder.ClearProviders()
        //Add to capture logs with ClearInsights Logging
        .AddClearInsightsLogger(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.ApiKey = "{ApiKey}";
            configuration.Secret = "{Environment Client Secret}";
            configuration.ApplicationName = "{Application Name}";
        }))
        .Build();
await host.StartAsync();

var logger = host.Services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
logger.LogInformation("Hello World!");
```

You can also easily implement [global exception handling](https://clearinsights.io/blog/clearinsights-net-global-exception-handling/) like:

```
System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UseClearInsightsExceptionHandling(host.Services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>());
```

It's also really good for [centralized log management](https://clearinsights.io) for agile teams.